# Docking Results window on right side of another ArcMap window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, gui, results-window

How can I dock **Results** window or similar other window on the right side of a window like **Catalog** and **Search** in ArcMap?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Drag the window and drop onto the indicator.
2. Click the "Pin" button at the top right of the window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Kadir
Explanation is really nice with small video :-).